# Run task on all available cores - Windows HPC Pack 2008 R2 SP4

Tags: job-scheduling, windows-clustering

I'm using Windows HPC Pack 2008 R2 SP4 to run a MPI application. I'm having problems getting the Job Scheduler to run the app on all available cores. Here's my code...

```
        using (IScheduler scheduler = new Scheduler())
        {
            scheduler.Connect("MyCluster");

            var newJob = scheduler.CreateJob();
            newJob.Name = "My job";
            //newJob.IsExclusive = true;

            var singleTask = newJob.CreateTask();
            singleTask.WorkDirectory = @"C:\MpiWorkspace";
            singleTask.CommandLine = @"mpiexec MyMpiApp.exe";
            newJob.AddTask(singleTask);
            scheduler.SubmitJob(newJob, null, null);
        }
```

Ran like the above I get allocated 1 (measly) core out of the 16 available across the two Compute Nodes in the cluster. The best I can get is by uncommenting the line `newJob.IsExclusive = true;`, which then allocates me all the cores on one of the Compute Nodes (8 cores).

If I was running from the command-line I could using the `mpiexec` switch `/np *` to use all available cores, but this appears to be overridden by the Job Scheduler.

How do I get the same effect in-code, how can I run on all available cores without explicitly declaring a minimum and maximum number of cores for the task?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solve it. I have similar problem. 
One thing I can think of is that you HPC scheduler override you affinity. Go to "Configuration" -> "Configure job scheduler policies and settings" -> "Affinity", set to "No Jobs"

you also need to add parameters to mpiexec

```
mpiexec -np * -al 2:L -c 8 MyMpiApp.exe
```

/al set the affinity
/c set cores per node

Not sure how to do it when your nodes have different number of cores.

Hope this helps